# Caret package Varimp - feature selection question

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, caret

I decided to use RFE using the caret package for feature selection for a logistic regression model.

The documentation says the Varimp for linear model uses

the absolute value of the t-statistic for each model parameter is used.

Logistic regression is not a linear model or has any of the linear model assumptions. Does it make sense to use linear model assumptions to reduce variables for a logistic regression problem using the caret package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wouldn't be making those assumptions. The logistic regression model falls into a wider class called generalized linear models (as does linear regression).

The t-test discussed here is the generalized linear model t-statistic to test that the parameter is equal to zero.

Comment: Max can i use this for a neural network model as well ?